# join two queries in Mysql

Tags: mysql

My database table have four columns:

```
src_ip   video_id  vlan_id  area      

query1= "SELECT area, count(*), count(DISTINCT video_id) FROM video_2 WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55' GROUP BY area"
query2= "SELECT area, count(*) as distinctCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT src_ip, vlan_id, area FROM video_2 WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55') distinctVideos GROUP BY area"
```

After executing query1, result is:

```
AREA   # of Total requests    # of Distinct video
area1  1234                   433
area2  3456                   234
...
```

After executing query2, result is:

```
AREA   # of users
area1  23
area2  34
area3  56
...
```

But how to join these two queries into one, then I can get the result in one data set:

```
AREA   total requests   # of distinct video   # of users   
area1  1234             433                   23
...
```

and after that how to sort the result descend or ascend based on "total requests" or "# of users", Where to add "ORDER BY" in the query?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am not missing anything, but maybe what you need is something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT area, count(*) as total_requests, count(DISTINCT video_id) as total_videos, count(DISTINCT src_ip) as total_users 
FROM video_2 
WHERE date_pl >= '2011-11-29 00:00' AND date_pl <= '2011-12-05 23:55'
GROUP BY area) as a ORDER BY total_requests
```

You could just as well do it without the outer select - just plug in the count(something) in the order by part.